# Process.Start not working IIS using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, process.start

Any idea of a work around using vb.net with ASP.NET.  Works great out of visual studio but can't get it to work on IIS 7.5 tried setting the load user profile in IIS on the application pool that didn't help either.  Any suggestions would be great.  Here is my process code

```
Process.Start(fileTempPath & "SearchDraw\" & fileName)
```

Comment: Do you have required permissions? Both to **access** that folder and to **execute** the specified file? Also an _external_ executable may try to access resources which are forbidden to IIS user.

Comment: The folder has permission as well as full permission on the IIS server..

Comment: What's the exact **error message**?

Comment: I'm actually not getting an error message.. it creates the file in my WIndows/Temp folder but then doesn't launch it.  I've tried doing the ProcessStartInfo route and it gets the error: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.

Comment: _"...it creates the file in my Windows\Temp folder..."_? Do you **create** that executable? Error message may be caused by, but not only, wrong target CPU (32/64 bit).

Comment: No I am finding a PDF on a server then pulling it to the Temp file and opening it as a pDF

Comment: What do you mean with _"...opening it as a PDF"_? When running from IIS your application won't open a PDF viewer (BTW IIS user is running a session without UI)

Comment: Okay so if I can't run a viewer when application is in IIS how can I go about opening the PDF in the Temp Folder..... or can I?

Comment: What do you need a PDF viewer **SERVER SIDE** for? Client can't see see the server screen, right?

Comment: Correct... I guess my question would be how can I get that PDF to open up automatically on the CLIENT side? or can I?

Comment: You can, just stream the generated pdf in a `object` tag, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use a Response to get it to open right in the users web browser...

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf"
Response.WriteFile(fileTempPath & "SearchDraw\" & fileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about this, but try creating an iFrame and setting the `src` attribute to the path to display the pdf client side:

```
<iframe src="mypdf.pdf"></iframe>
```